# Notepad++ regular expression find a "," and replace odd "," with "." in every row

Tags: regex, notepad++

I ran into a mess recently with my data aquisition program which saves four datapoints separated by a comma(csv format) every couple of milliseconds. I used a PC (NL region) where the decimal point is a "," for data acquisition.

Now when i try to import my csv file to matlab/excel it gives me 8 columns (which should be 4) as all the decimals are also printed as ","

Is there a way to use regular expression in notepad++ (for eg) to find all "," in a row, and replace the odd ones to a "."?

Thanks a lot for any help. I have thousands of rows of data such that doing it manually will take ages.

**Example raw data:**
0,000000,293,625871,331,588659,37,440656
0,049000,294,148003,332,215504,37,400764
0,098000,294,814740,332,944775,37,261284
0,145000,295,683491,333,688803,37,184621
0,193000,296,504183,334,271264,37,058032
0,241000,297,213232,334,704293,37,109150
0,289000,297,595142,335,081749,37,113087
0,339000,297,968663,335,292896,37,088883
0,403000,298,204013,335,796915,37,109307

**How the processed data should look:**
0.000000,293.625871,331.588659,37.440656
0.049000,294.148003,332.215504,37.400764
0.098000,294.814740,332.944775,37.261284
0.145000,295.683491,333.688803,37.184621
0.193000,296.504183,334.271264,37.058032
0.241000,297.213232,334.704293,37.109150
0.289000,297.595142,335.081749,37.113087
0.339000,297.968663,335.292896,37.088883
0.403000,298.204013,335.796915,37.109307

Comment: `/[,]+/` to match all commas and then replace with `.`

Comment: Thanks! I would like to replace just the odd "," and not all. What should the regex code to find odd ","?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just simply do:

Find what: `(\d+),(\d+)`
Replace with: `$1.$2`

Then clic on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

To match all odd commas, use a look ahead that asserts an *even* number of commas follow:

```
 ,(?=(([^,]*,){2})*[^,]*$)
```

Comment: Thanks, but notepad++ was still finding all the commas (not just the odd ones). The solution from @JE SUIS CHARLIE solved my problem as long replace all twice. :)