# Add text after the first instance of a word (notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of phrases like this

```
Mike is Russia, He is 28 y.o.
Elena is UK, She is 30 y.o.
```

and I want to add a "from" after the first "is" and not the second "is" so it becomes:

```
Mike is from Russia, He is 28 y.o.
Elena is from UK, She is 30 y.o.
```

Comment: A simple approach without regex would be to use `Find and replace` on `is ` to `is from `

Comment: The proble is this will replace also the second "is" with "is from" so it will become "Mike is from Russia, He is from 28 y.o."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++, in find and replace, use search mode Regular expression, in Find use
`(^.*?(is))` and in Replace
`\1 from`

This regular expression find from start of line to first 'is' occurred and then append found text with 'from'

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex and replace odd occurrences of "is" with "is from".

See this links for reference:
[replace odd occurrences of a character using regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370777/replace-odd-occurrences-of-a-character-using-regex-in-javascript)
[Notepad++ regular expression find a "," and replace odd "," with "." in every row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792666/notepad-regular-expression-find-a-and-replace-odd-with-in-every-ro)